# Ordering a list sequentially but remove lower values that appear later

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[5000, 4000, 3500, 4200, 3300]
```

And I want to order this list from high to low, but also remove any values that have already been 'beat' by a lower value appearing earlier in the list. So above list should look like this:

```
[5000, 4000, 3500, 3300]
```

I have tried looping over the list and comparing it to every other value, but I am getting lost in for-loops. I think I am missing something very obvious.

Any help or other article is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, your question is unclear, with the example you gave I do not see any sorting. please provides a more meaningful example so we can help you

Comment: what happens if there are 2 equal values? Are they both stored or not?

Comment: all the answers so far only does filtering and no sorting.  You need a better example if you want sorting as well or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'beat' by a lower value appearing earlier in the list` means you can 
record the current minimum number, and compare to it. If larger than minimum number, remove it, If less than it, append to result and update the minimum.

Time complexity: O(n)
Space complexity: O(1)

```
def trim_list_high_to_low(nums):
    min_num = float('inf')
    result = []
    for num in nums:
        if num <= min_num:
            result.append(num)
            min_num = num
    return result
```

output:
`[5000, 4000, 3500, 3300]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried something like this but made errors I guess. Thanksss!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
d = [5000, 4000, 3500, 4200, 3300]
new_d = [a for i, a in enumerate(d) if not i or d[i-1] > a]
```

Output:

```
[5000, 4000, 3500, 3300]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a snippet like this:

```
prev = 2**31
nlist = []
for i in your_list:
    if i < prev:
        nlist.append(i)
        prev = i
```

`nlist` result:

```
 [5000, 4000, 3500, 3300]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that only compares each number with the last value of `new_d`:

```
d = [5000, 4000, 3500, 4200, 3300]
new_d = d[:1]
for item in d[1:]:
    if item < new_d[-1]:
        new_d.append(item)
print(new_d)

>>> [5000, 4000, 3500, 3300]
```